# How do I pop a dialog on page load, gather data, then refresh the original page with the new data in jQuery Mobile?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I saw a similar question here on SO for passing data back from a dialog, but the answer wasn't very satisfactory. I'm not finding an intuitive way to do this.

My requirements are to have a page that displays a report, and an options dialog for setting parameters. This is an ASP.NET MVC3 app.

I'm using the following to show my dialog when the page first loads:

```
$('#index').live('pageinit', function () {
        if (showDialog) {
            $.mobile.changePage('@Url.Action("Options", "MyController")', { transition: 'pop', role: 'dialog' });                 
        }
    });
```

My options page has a form and a back and ok button. With my back button set up as follows:

```
<a id="btnCancel" href="#" data-icon="back" data-role="button" data-rel="back">Cancel</a>
```

I can't get this to close the dialog without firing the pageinit event again. I've tried with pagecreate event, because that is supposed to fire once, yet it fires every time.

At this point, I don't even know how to get the dialog data back to the original page. IMO this should be something very easy to do, yet I'm finding it very challenging within this framework. If there is no easy way, is it possible to utilize the jQuery UI Dialog within jQuery Mobile?

Thank you in advance for your help.